# Javascript issue installing npm packages (nodemon, express)

Tags: javascript, node.js, npm

I'm new to js and trying to setup a simple project with express and nodemon via npm.
However, installing these packages does give me multiple errors (see below).
I am on Win 10, using the PowerShell & Atom IDE. Project is saved on Google Drive.
"Calc.js" is simply the name of my project.

I have node & npm installed and restarted pc multiple times before.
[image]

Then I set up the npm init
[image]

I begin to install the first package and get this error:
[image]

I try to install express, but get the same result, adding -g also does not make a difference. Now I install "ci", which works for some reason.

[image]

Now I have the node modules folder in my project, try to install express again, and it seems to kinda work (got the files in the node_modules folder).

[image]
[image]
[image]

However when I try to run the calc.js via "node calc.js" it
does not work. [image]

Already tried out many things and even accidentally made it work, then tried to reproduce it and failed. Would be super happy for some help.

Comment: This might be some sort of permission error, try recreating the project outside of a Google Drive directory and see if that works.

Comment: Also if you want to have access to a project on multiple devices I'd suggest using something like [GitHub](https://github.com/) instead of Google Drive.

Comment: Yeah this worked..Damn .. so much wasted time.. thanks a bunch for the quick answer